# InvalidIndexError while doing fillna on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Notes, my df only 1000 x 20 each

Here my `df`

```
poi_name     column_1     column_2     column_3    column_4
block             uts          NaN          NaN         tyi
block             utr          NaN          NaN         tyi
```

Her'e my `df1`

```
poi_name     column_1     column_3     column_5
block             uta          yuw          tyu
```

Here's what I did

```
df = df.set_index('poi_name')
df1 = df1.set_index('poi_name')
df = df.fillna(df1)
```

Here's the error message

```
nvalidIndexError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in fillna(self, value, method, axis, inplace, limit, downcast)
   4325             inplace=inplace,
   4326             limit=limit,
-> 4327             downcast=downcast,
   4328         )
   4329 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in fillna(self, value, method, axis, inplace, limit, downcast)
   6084                 )
   6085             elif isinstance(value, ABCDataFrame) and self.ndim == 2:
-> 6086                 new_data = self.where(self.notna(), value)._data
   6087             else:
   6088                 raise ValueError(f"invalid fill value with a {type(value)}")

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in where(self, cond, other, inplace, axis, level, errors, try_cast)
   9009         other = com.apply_if_callable(other, self)
   9010         return self._where(
-> 9011             cond, other, inplace, axis, level, errors=errors, try_cast=try_cast
   9012         )
   9013 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _where(self, cond, other, inplace, axis, level, errors, try_cast)
   8792                     other._get_axis(i).equals(ax) for i, ax in enumerate(self.axes)
   8793                 ):
-> 8794                     raise InvalidIndexError
   8795 
   8796             # slice me out of the other

InvalidIndexError:
```

Comment: can you provide the inputs as DataFrame constructor? I cannot reproduce your issue (works fine for me)

Comment: I think it because duplication in `poi_name` in `df`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, I cannot reproduce it. Here is the full code, using pandas version 1.4.1:

```
from numpy import nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'poi_name': ['block', 'block'],
                   'column_1': ['uts', 'utr'],
                   'column_2': [nan, nan],
                   'column_3': [nan, nan],
                   'column_4': ['tyi', 'tyi']})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'poi_name': ['block'],
                    'column_1': ['uta'],
                    'column_3': ['yuw'],
                    'column_5': ['tyu']})

df = df.set_index('poi_name')
df1 = df1.set_index('poi_name')
df = df.fillna(df1)

print(df)
```

output:

```
         column_1 column_2 column_3 column_4
poi_name                                    
block         uts      NaN      yuw      tyi
block         utr      NaN      yuw      tyi
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your error as well.
But in my case, duplicated index in `df1` seems to be the root cause.
Adding `df1.drop_duplicates('poi_name')` can solve my issue.